# Returning the column header with a value in its row

Tags: arrays, excel, function, if-statement, formula

I have 24 column headers with a date (K6:AH6)

I need to return the column header that has a number in it aka a non blank. the number of value is either 1,2,3,4

There are 1120 non blank and number rows (k7:ah1120)

[image]

I want column J7 to show up as Jul 2016 because cell Q7 has a value in it.

the kicker is that 75 of the 1120 rows have a value in 2 or more columns. I may manually do these or insert a row to turn the value back to 1. Not sure how to depict this in a formulation. TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in J7 and copy down:

```
=INDEX($K$6:$AHT$6,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($K7:$AH7<>"",),0))
```

[image]